# Reformatting a csv file, script is confused by ' %." '

Tags: bash

I'm using bash on cygwin.

I have to take a .csv file that is a subset of a much larger set of settings and shuffle the new csv settings (same keys, different values) into the 1000-plus-line original, making a new .json file.

I have put together a script to automate this. The first step in the process is to "clean up" the csv file by extracting lines that start with "mme " and "sms ". Everything else is to pass through cleanly to the "clean" .csv file.

This routine is as follows:

```
# clean up the settings, throwing out mme and sms entries
cat extract.csv | while read -r LINE; do 
    if [[ $LINE == "mme "* ]]
        then 
            printf "$LINE\n" >> mme_settings.csv
        elif [[ $LINE == "sms "* ]] 
            then 
            printf "$LINE\n" >> sms_settings.csv 
        else 
            printf "$LINE\n" >> extract_clean.csv
    fi
done
```

My problem is that this thing stubs its toe on the following string at the end of one entry:  `100%."` When it's done with the line, it simply elides the `%."` and the new-line marker following it, and smears the two lines together:

```
... 100next.entry.keyname...
```

I would love to reach in and simply manually delimit the `%` sign, but it's not a realistic option for my use case. Clearly I'm missing something. My suspicion is that I am in some wise abusing `cat` or `read` in the first line.

If there is some place I should have looked to find the answer before bugging you all, by all means point me in that direction and I'll sod off.

Comment: printf interprets the % after expanding the $LINE variable. use `echo` instead. (I think)

Comment: njzk2 wins the kewpie doll! 

When's the right time to use printf vs. echo?

Comment: use printf when you need to format a string, i.e. when you need to use the percent formatting capabilities. in all other cases, use echo

Answer (score 4):

Syntax for `printf` is :

```
printf format [argument]...
```

In [[ printf ]](http://ss64.com/bash/printf.html) format string, anything followed by `%` is a format specifier as described in the link above. What you would like to do is :

```
while read -r line; do # Replaced LINE with line, full uppercase variable are reserved for the syste,
    if [[ "$line" = "mme "* ]] # Here* would glob for anything that comes next
        then 
            printf "%s\n" $line >> mme_settings.csv
        elif [[ "$line" = "sms "* ]] 
        then 
            printf "%s\n" $line >> sms_settings.csv 
        else 
            printf "%s\n" $line >> extract_clean.csv
    fi
done<extract.csv  # Avoided the useless use of cat
```

Comment: Isn't `=~` wrong here? We don't want regex matching, just simple globbing.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Why globbing here?

Comment: We're just matching lines starting with, for example, `sms`, which is matched by the glob `"sms "*`. If the same is interpreted as a regex, what is `*` referring to? Also, it's probably slower using the regex engine.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Sorry that was careless me. Corrected. :)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, your problem is expanding a parameter containing a formatting instruction in the formatting argument of `printf`, which can be solved by using `echo` instead or moving the parameter to be expanded out of the formatting string, as demonstrated in other answers.

I recommend not looping over your whole file with Bash in the first place, as it's notoriously slow; you're extracting lines starting with certain patterns, which is a job at which grep excels:

```
grep '^mme ' extract.csv > mme_settings.csv
grep '^sms ' extract.csv > sms_settings.csv
grep -v '^mme \|^sms ' extract.csv > extract_clean.csv
```

The third command uses the `-v` option (extract lines that *don't* match) and alternation to exclude lines both starting with `mme` and `sms`.

Comment: This will be way faster than the original approach.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Last week, it was 5 hours by hand. I've got it down to a minute (at the expense of days that I don't want to talk about...). Yeah, I know my code is slow, but it's >95% accurate, and futzing with the echo vs. printf stuff should get me to 100nextline D'Oh!